# Tensorflow always outputs same prediction

Tags: input, tensorflow, pipeline

I am building a binary classifier with my own image pipeline. The images are 178x65 (wxh) greyscale jpgs. It loads the images and their labels correctly, and fits all of the layer sizes correctly, but for some reason, it always outputs the same prediction for every image ([ 1.  0.]). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
# Example on how to use the tensorflow input pipelines. The explanation can be found here ischlag.github.io.
import tensorflow as tf
import random
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

dataset_path      = "./v5-tensorflow/"
test_labels_file  = "test-labels.csv"
train_labels_file = "train-labels.csv"

test_set_size = 39

IMAGE_HEIGHT  = 65
IMAGE_WIDTH   = 178
NUM_CHANNELS  = 1
BATCH_SIZE    = 39

def encode_label(label):

  if label == "kalli\n":
      return [0, 1]
  elif label == "francisco\n":
      return [1, 0]
  else:
      print("SOMETHING WENT WRONG")
      return [0, 0]

def read_label_file(file):
  f = open(file, "r")
  filepaths = []
  labels = []
  for line in f:
    filepath, label = line.split(",")
    filepaths.append(filepath)
    labels.append(encode_label(label))
  return filepaths, labels

# reading labels and file path
train_filepaths, train_labels = read_label_file(dataset_path + train_labels_file)
test_filepaths, test_labels = read_label_file(dataset_path + test_labels_file)

# transform relative path into full path
train_filepaths = [ dataset_path + fp for fp in train_filepaths]
test_filepaths = [ dataset_path + fp for fp in test_filepaths]

# convert string into tensors
train_images = ops.convert_to_tensor(train_filepaths, dtype=dtypes.string)
test_images = ops.convert_to_tensor(test_filepaths, dtype=dtypes.string)
train_labels = ops.convert_to_tensor(train_labels, dtype=dtypes.int32)
test_labels = ops.convert_to_tensor(test_labels, dtype=dtypes.int32)

# create input queues
train_input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer(
                                    [train_images, train_labels],
                                    shuffle=True)
test_input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer(
                                    [test_images, test_labels],
                                    shuffle=True)

# process path and string tensor into an image and a label
file_content = tf.read_file(train_input_queue[0])
train_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_content, channels=NUM_CHANNELS)
train_label = train_input_queue[1]

file_content = tf.read_file(test_input_queue[0])
test_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_content, channels=NUM_CHANNELS)
test_label = test_input_queue[1]

# define tensor shape
train_image.set_shape([IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, NUM_CHANNELS])
test_image.set_shape([IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, NUM_CHANNELS])

# collect batches of images before processing
# train_image_batch, train_label_batch
train_batch = tf.train.batch(
                                    [train_image, train_label],
                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
                                    #,num_threads=1
                                    )
# test_image_batch, test_label_batch
test_batch = tf.train.batch(
                                    [test_image, test_label],
                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
                                    #,num_threads=1
                                    )

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 65, 178, 1], name="x")
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name="y_")
#
def weight_variable(shape, n):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial, name=n)

def bias_variable(shape, n):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial, name=n)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
#
input_reshape = tf.reshape(x, [-1,65,178,1])

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32], "w1")
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32], "b1")

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(input_reshape, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1) # 33x89x32
#
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64], "w2")
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64], "b2")

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2) # now 17x45x64

W_conv3 = weight_variable([5, 5, 64, 128], "w3")
b_conv3 = bias_variable([128], "b3")

h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)
h_pool3 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv3)# 9x23x128

W_conv4 = weight_variable([5, 5, 128, 256], "w4")
b_conv4 = bias_variable([256], "b4")

h_conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool3, W_conv4) + b_conv4)
h_pool4 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv4) # 5x12x256

W_fc1 = weight_variable([5 * 12 * 256, 5120], "w5")
b_fc1 = bias_variable([5120], "b5")

h_pool4_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool4, [-1, 5*12*256])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool4_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1) # 1x5120

W_fc2 = weight_variable([5120, 2], "w6")
b_fc2 = bias_variable([2], "b6") # 1x2

y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2, name="softmax")
y_clipped = tf.clip_by_value(y_conv, 1e-10, 0.9999999)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_clipped), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_clipped, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1), name="correct")
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), name="accuracy")
saver = tf.train.Saver()

print("input pipeline ready")

with tf.Session() as sess:

  # initialize the variables
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  # initialize the queue threads to start to shovel data
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  print("from the train set:")

  for i in range(62):
      batch = sess.run(train_batch)

      if i % 3 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
            x:batch[0], y_: batch[1]
            })
        print("step %d, training accuracy %.2f" % (i, train_accuracy))

      train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})


  saver.save(sess, "model.ckpt")
  tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '', 'graph.pb')

  t_batch = sess.run(test_batch)
  print("test accuracy %g" % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: t_batch[0], y_: t_batch[1]
  }))

  # stop our queue threads and properly close the session
  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
  sess.close()
```

Comment: Did you see how loss is changing ? If loss is not reducing, increase learning rate or change Adam to RMSprop and see how loss changes. Run atleast 2-3 epochs to see change in output/loss values.